# How to avoid in eclipse a key input going into the console? (issue with the ":" key while running Pyraf task)

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I understand this is a extremely specialized question but I have no idea where else to ask for support

I am using Eclipse (with pydev) to run my python scripts. In this particular library (called PYRAF, which based on an old piece of software known as PYRAF) you can open windows/run tasks which you can use to interact with your data (keys, mouse...)

Mouse and single keys work fine, however when I try to use the ":" symbol (pressing "shift" + ".") this event goes into the console instead of going to the window of the program currently running: I can see the ":" symbol in the Eclipse console instead of being recognized but the Pyraf window.

I think it only happens with this key... Any idea how could I solve this issue?

P.S. I am getting this warning but I do not know if it is related to this issue or if is one of the many issues with IRAF tasks:

```
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
```

Comment: As I remember it correctly it is a buggy implementation of the console in eclipse. In the passed I've solved it by setting up an external tool to gnome-terminal and use it that way.

Comment: Yeap, the real issue is that the Eclipse console view is not a real terminal.